# How to Input numbers in python until certain string is entered

Tags: python

I am completing questions from a python book when I came across this question.

> Write a program which repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters "done". Once done is entered, print out total, count, and average of the numbers.

My issue here is that I do not know how to check if a user specifically entered the string 'done' while the computer is explicitly checking for numbers. Here is how I approached the problem instead.

```
#Avg, Sum, and count program

total = 0
count = 0
avg = 0
num = None

# Ask user to input number, if number is 0 print calculations
while (num != 0):
    try:
        num = float(input('(Enter \'0\' when complete.) Enter num: '))
    except:
        print('Error, invalid input.')
        continue

    count = count + 1
    total = total + num

avg = total / count
print('Average: ' + str(avg) + '\nCount: ' + str(count) + '\nTotal: ' + str(total))
```

Instead of doing what it asked for, let the user enter 'done' to complete the program, I used an integer (0) to see if the user was done inputting numbers.

Comment: Then don't convert it to a number immediately.

Comment: You test for the value to be equal to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach that would solve your problem would be as following :

```
input_str = input('(Enter \'0\' when complete.) Enter num: ')
if (input_str.isdigit()):
    num = float(input_str)
else:
    if (input_str == "done"):
        done()
    else:
        error()
```

This way you control cases in which a digit was entered and the cases in which a string was entered (Not via a try/except scheme).

Comment: try-except is always preferred over if-else in Python. See [the EAFP principle in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python).

Comment: I can agree its better to be safe then sorry but in this specific case, you lose 'control' over the analyzing of the input when using the try/except scheme.

Comment: @Rohi Thank you very much for your help =)  .isdigit() is very powerful

Comment: @Rohi, it shouldn't matter much, but, I've added my answer showing how to use EAFP principle for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping your *Try-Except* approach, you can simply check if the string that user inputs is `done` without converting to float, and break the `while` loop. Also, it's always better to specify the error you want to catch. `ValueError` in this case.

```
while True:
    num = input('(Enter \'done\' when complete.) Enter num: ')
    if num == 'done':
        break
    try:
        num = float(num)
    except ValueError:
        print('Error, invalid input.')
        continue
```